# Python+Chaco+Traits - rendering bug: unexpected fills of line plot of large data?

Tags: python, enthought, chaco, traitsui

Using the minimal example below, the line plot of a large (some 110k points) plot I get (with python 2.7, numpy 1.5.1, chaco/enable/traits 4.3.0) is this:

[image: chaco01]

However, that is bizarre, because it is a line plot, and there shouldn't be any filled areas in there? Especially since the data is sawtooth-ish signal? It's as if there is a line at y~=37XX, above which there is color filling?! But sure enough, if I zoom into an area, I get the rendering I expect - without the unexpected fill:

[image: chaco02]

Is this a bug - or is there something I'm doing wrong? I tried to use `use_downsampling`, but it makes no difference...

The test code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
from pprint import pprint
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from chaco.api import Plot, ArrayPlotData, VPlotContainer
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from enable.component_editor import ComponentEditor
from chaco.tools.api import PanTool, BetterSelectingZoom

tlen = 112607
alr = npr.randint(0, 4000, tlen)
tx = np.arange(0.0, 30.0-0.00001, 30.0/tlen)
ty = np.arange(0, tlen, 1) % 10000 + alr
pprint(len(ty))


class ChacoTest(HasTraits):

  container = Instance(VPlotContainer)
  traits_view = View(
    Item('container', editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False),
    width=800, height=500, resizable=True,
    title="Chaco Test"
  )

  def __init__(self):
    super(ChacoTest, self).__init__()
    pprint(ty)
    self.plotdata = ArrayPlotData(x = tx, y = ty)
    self.plotobj = Plot(self.plotdata)
    self.plotA = self.plotobj.plot(("x", "y"), type="line", color=(0,0.99,0), spacing=0, padding=0, alpha=0.7, use_downsampling=True)
    self.container = VPlotContainer(self.plotobj, spacing=5, padding=5, bgcolor="lightgray")
    #~ container.add(plot)
    self.plotobj.tools.append(PanTool(self.plotobj))
    self.plotobj.overlays.append(BetterSelectingZoom(self.plotobj))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ChacoTest().configure_traits()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the error and talking with John Wiggins (maintainer of Enable), it is a bug in kiva (which chaco uses to paint on the screen):
https://github.com/enthought/enable
The good news is that this is a bug in one of the kiva backend that you can use. So to go around the issue, you can run your script choosing a different backend:

```
ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4.qpainter python <NAME OF YOUR SCRIPT>
```

if you use qpainter or quartz, the plot looks (on my machine) as expected. If you choose qt4.image (the Agg backend), you will reproduce the issue. Unfortunately, the Agg backend is the default one. To change that, you can set the ETS_TOOLKIT environment variable to that value:

```
export ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4.qpainter
```

The bad news is that fixing this isn't going to be an easy task. Please feel free to report the bug in github (again https://github.com/enthought/enable) if you want to be involved in this. If you don't, I will log it in the next couple of days. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Thanks for that, @jonathanrocher - and apologies for the late accept! I was/am quite busy with other things in this period, I haven't even had the time to get a github account yet `:)` So I hope you felt free to log the bug... Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Disappointing results with other backends (on Windows). qt4.qpainter is much slower (and uglier), qt4.gl and qt4.cairo crash. qt4.quartz seems to be for OS X only?

Answer (score 0):

Just a note - I found this:

[[Enthought-Dev] is chaco faster than matplotlib](https://mail.enthought.com/pipermail/enthought-dev/2010-November/027515.html)

> I recall reading somewhere that you are expected to implement the
>   _downsample method because the optimal algorithm depends on the type
>   of data you're collecting.

And as I couldn't find any examples with _downsample implementation other than [decimated_plot.py](http://bitbucket.org/bburan/neurobehavior/src/tip/cns/widgets/views/decimated_plot.py) referred in that post, which isn't standalone - I tried and built a standalone example, included below.

The example basically has messed up drag and zoom, (plot disappears if you go out of range, or stretches upon a drag move) - and it starts zoomed in; but it is possible to zoom it out in the range shown in the OP - and then it displays the *exact* same plot rendering problem. So downsampling isn't the solution per se, so this is likely a bug?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
from pprint import pprint
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from chaco.api import Plot, ArrayPlotData, VPlotContainer
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from enable.component_editor import ComponentEditor
from chaco.tools.api import PanTool, BetterSelectingZoom
#
from chaco.api import BaseXYPlot, LinearMapper, AbstractPlotData
from enable.api import black_color_trait, LineStyle
from traits.api import Float, Enum, Int, Str, Trait, Event, Property, Array, cached_property, Bool, Dict
from chaco.abstract_mapper import AbstractMapper
from chaco.abstract_data_source import AbstractDataSource
from chaco.array_data_source import ArrayDataSource
from chaco.data_range_1d import DataRange1D


tlen = 112607
alr = npr.randint(0, 4000, tlen)
tx = np.arange(0.0, 30.0-0.00001, 30.0/tlen)
ty = np.arange(0, tlen, 1) % 10000 + alr
pprint(len(ty))


class ChacoTest(HasTraits):

  container = Instance(VPlotContainer)
  traits_view = View(
    Item('container', editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False),
    width=800, height=500, resizable=True,
    title="Chaco Test"
  )

  downsampling_cutoff = Int(4)

  def __init__(self):
    super(ChacoTest, self).__init__()
    pprint(ty)
    self.plotdata = ArrayPlotData(x = tx, y = ty)
    self.plotobj = TimeSeriesPlot(self.plotdata)
    self.plotobj.setplotranges("x", "y")
    self.container = VPlotContainer(self.plotobj, spacing=5, padding=5, bgcolor="lightgray")
    self.plotobj.tools.append(PanTool(self.plotobj))
    self.plotobj.overlays.append(BetterSelectingZoom(self.plotobj))


# decimate from:
# https://bitbucket.org/mjrosen/neurobehavior/raw/097ef3719d1263a8b303d29c31ab71b6e792ab04/cns/widgets/views/decimated_plot.py

def decimate(data, screen_width, downsampling_cutoff=4, mode='extremes'):
  data_width = data.shape[-1]
  downsample = np.floor((data_width/screen_width)/4.)
  if downsample > downsampling_cutoff:
    return globals()['decimate_'+mode](data, downsample)
  else:
    return data

def decimate_extremes(data, downsample):
  last_dim = data.ndim
  offset = data.shape[-1] % downsample
  if data.ndim == 2:
    shape = (len(data), -1, downsample)
  else:
    shape = (-1, downsample)
  data = data[..., offset:].reshape(shape).copy()
  data_min = data.min(last_dim)
  data_max = data.max(last_dim)
  return data_min, data_max

def decimate_mean(data, downsample):
  offset = len(data) % downsample
  if data.ndim == 2:
    shape = (-1, downsample, data.shape[-1])
  else:
    shape = (-1, downsample)
  data = data[offset:].reshape(shape).copy()
  return data.mean(1)

# based on class from decimated_plot.py, also
# neurobehavior/cns/chaco_exts/timeseries_plot.py ;
# + some other code from chaco
class TimeSeriesPlot(BaseXYPlot):

  color = black_color_trait
  line_width = Float(1.0)
  line_style = LineStyle
  reference = Enum('most_recent', 'trigger')

  traits_view = View("color@", "line_width")
  downsampling_cutoff = Int(100)

  signal_trait = "updated"
  decimate_mode = Str('extremes')
  ch_index = Trait(None, Int, None)

  # Mapping of data names from self.data to their respective datasources.
  datasources = Dict(Str, Instance(AbstractDataSource))
  index_mapper = Instance(AbstractMapper)
  value_mapper = Instance(AbstractMapper)

  def __init__(self, data=None, **kwargs):
    super(TimeSeriesPlot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self._index_mapper_changed(None, self.index_mapper)
    self.setplotdata(data)
    self._plot_ui_info = None
    return

  def setplotdata(self, data):
    if data is not None:
      if isinstance(data, AbstractPlotData):
        self.data = data
      elif type(data) in (ndarray, tuple, list):
        self.data = ArrayPlotData(data)
      else:
        raise ValueError, "Don't know how to create PlotData for data" \
                  "of type " + str(type(data))

  def setplotranges(self, index_name, value_name):
    self.index_name = index_name
    self.value_name = value_name
    index = self._get_or_create_datasource(index_name)
    value = self._get_or_create_datasource(value_name)
    if not(self.index_mapper):
      imap = LinearMapper()#(range=self.index_range)
      self.index_mapper = imap
    if not(self.value_mapper):
      vmap = LinearMapper()#(range=self.value_range)
      self.value_mapper = vmap
    if not(self.index_range): self.index_range = DataRange1D() # calls index_mapper
    if not(self.value_range): self.value_range = DataRange1D()
    self.index_range.add(index) # calls index_mapper!
    self.value_range.add(value)
    # now do it (right?):
    self.index_mapper = LinearMapper(range=self.index_range)
    self.value_mapper = LinearMapper(range=self.value_range)

  def _get_or_create_datasource(self, name):
    if name not in self.datasources:
      data = self.data.get_data(name)
      if type(data) in (list, tuple):
        data = array(data)
      if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
        if len(data.shape) == 1:
          ds = ArrayDataSource(data, sort_order="none")
        elif len(data.shape) == 2:
          ds = ImageData(data=data, value_depth=1)
        elif len(data.shape) == 3:
          if data.shape[2] in (3,4):
            ds = ImageData(data=data, value_depth=int(data.shape[2]))
          else:
            raise ValueError("Unhandled array shape in creating new plot: " \
                     + str(data.shape))
      elif isinstance(data, AbstractDataSource):
        ds = data
      else:
        raise ValueError("Couldn't create datasource for data of type " + \
                 str(type(data)))
      self.datasources[name] = ds
    return self.datasources[name]

  def get_screen_points(self):
    self._gather_points()
    return self._downsample()

  def _data_changed(self):
    self.invalidate_draw()
    self._cache_valid = False
    self._screen_cache_valid = False
    self.request_redraw()

  def _gather_points(self):
    if not self._cache_valid:
      range = self.index_mapper.range
      #if self.reference == 'most_recent':
      #  values, t_lb, t_ub = self.get_recent_range(range.low, range.high)
      #else:
      #  values, t_lb, t_ub = self.get_range(range.low, range.high, -1)
      values, t_lb, t_ub = self.data[self.value_name][range.low:range.high], range.low, range.high
      #if self.ch_index is None:
      #  self._cached_data = values
      #else:
      #  #self._cached_data = values[:,self.ch_index]
      self._cached_data = values
      self._cached_data_bounds = t_lb, t_ub
      self._cache_valid = True
      self._screen_cache_valid = False

  def _downsample(self):
    if not self._screen_cache_valid:
      val_pts = self._cached_data
      screen_min, screen_max = self.index_mapper.screen_bounds
      screen_width = screen_max-screen_min
      values = decimate(val_pts, screen_width, self.downsampling_cutoff,
                self.decimate_mode)
      if type(values) == type(()):
        n = len(values[0])
        s_val_min = self.value_mapper.map_screen(values[0])
        s_val_max = self.value_mapper.map_screen(values[1])
        self._cached_screen_data = s_val_min, s_val_max
      else:
        s_val_pts = self.value_mapper.map_screen(values)
        self._cached_screen_data = s_val_pts
        n = len(values)
      t = np.linspace(*self._cached_data_bounds, num=n)
      t_screen = self.index_mapper.map_screen(t)
      self._cached_screen_index = t_screen
      self._screen_cache_valid = True
    return [self._cached_screen_index, self._cached_screen_data]

  def _render(self, gc, points):
    idx, val = points
    if len(idx) == 0:
      return
    gc.save_state()
    gc.set_antialias(True)
    gc.clip_to_rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    gc.set_stroke_color(self.color_)
    gc.set_line_width(self.line_width)
    #gc.set_line_width(5)
    gc.begin_path()
    #if len(val) == 2:
    if type(val) == type(()):
      starts = np.column_stack((idx, val[0]))
      ends = np.column_stack((idx, val[1]))
      gc.line_set(starts, ends)
    else:
      gc.lines(np.column_stack((idx, val)))
    gc.stroke_path()
    self._draw_default_axes(gc)
    gc.restore_state()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ChacoTest().configure_traits()
```